# Looking for a way to find up to, and including a specific selector

Tags: jquery, selector

I'm trying to find the closest previous sibling that has a class called `hide`.

Eg:

```
<div class="hide">A</div>
<div class="hide">B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
<div class="start">E</div>
```

I need the script to find B, but NOT A, when using `.start` as the starting point.

Here's what I have so far

```
$('.start').prevUntil('.hide');
```

Of course that doesn't work because `prevUntil` doesn't include the selector once it's found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I think I found an easy answer, just use the `:first` option:

```
$('.start').prevUntil('.hide:first');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var collection = $('.start').prevUntil('.hide');
collection.add(collection.prev());
```